# How to create PDF in Visual Studio 2012 from database fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I have developed a membership management application for an NGO, and now they asked me to develop a module which can create a PDF document from the database fields. I mean a system generated pdf file which contains name, address, subscription type, member photograph on it etc. Does anybody have any idea.

Comment: I created once pdf from database fields please wait I searching in my code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. I want to generate a pdf report from user input or from existing database

Comment: Let me try this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iTextSharp,you can do it.It can be download from internet and it is free. Please, find the code below,

```
public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
 {      
   Document document = new Document();
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c://sample.pdf", FileMode.Create));
  document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
PdfPRow row = null;
float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };

table.SetWidths(widths);

table.WidthPercentage = 100;
int iCol = 0;
string colname = "";
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));

cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
{

    table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
}

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
    }          
}  document.Add(table);
    document.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use PDFSharp & Migradoc for this http://www.pdfsharp.net/

Answer (score 0):

We've used [PDF Sharp](http://itextpdf.com/) in the past and found it to be pretty good. My previous employer used [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) which is excellent although it is a paid for solution.

I've also heard good things about [iTextPDF](http://itextpdf.com/)